# Cannot present UIAlertController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I've this function

```
func showMessageNew(msg:String,title: String){
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true)
}
```

But when I run it I've this in the console: `whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: Inorder to show an alert, you need one parent view. Where are you using this function ?

Comment: your function is in viewDidLoad  o viewAppear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code can be used to present the `UIAlertController`,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            self.showMessageNew(msg: "hi", title: "hi")
            }
        }

    func showMessageNew(msg:String,title: String){
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
}
```